# Bars not displayed in d3 bar graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to run this example of a simple d3 bar graph, http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304. I get the following output
[image]

I cannot see any bars and the background of the svg is fully the color of the bars.

Comment: can you post your code...its difficult to guide what mistake you are committing without the code:)

Comment: Yes, please post the code. You probably messed up your ordinal (horizontal) axis logic. I see that the bar that was at position E probably takes the whole chart width.